# Is there an algorithm to hide text in another text, while preserving the meaning of the latter?

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, reference-request, steganography

Is there a way to hide a text message $A$ inside another text $B$ using a cryptographic cipher/algorithm, while preserving the sense/meaning of $B$ and without anybody being able to notice there is a message $A$ hidden in text $B$?

I am looking for something that can be processed either manually or by a computer.

For clarification: I don't mean to hide a message like `“Attack X”` saying `“I went to X on holiday this summer”` but an actual cipher/algorithm.

I know for sure there must be something, but being new to cryptographic and not knowing much about it, I don’t know where to look or what to look for. Is there a way to achieve this? If there is, could you (besides a reference) also provide a short example?

Comment: What you are looking for is called [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography). Questions about steganography can [be on topic here](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/197/are-questions-about-steganography-on-topic-here), if it is the right kind of question.

Comment: No, I know stenography... I don't want to add hidden messages in (image/audio/any) files but in text that can be printed or written on paper.

I'm not looking to use that

Comment: Steganography can be in text, text that can be printed or written on paper. For example, hide your message in the first letter of every paragraph. Here is [another example](http://www.spammimic.com/explain.shtml)

Comment: You can also use whitespace at the end of lines to transmit messages, misspellings, etc.

Comment: @mikeazo I'm not trying to "encrypt" it with PGP/GPG.

And yeah, I know about the acronym on each line's first letter, but that would be too obvious.
And whitetext would be useless on paper and handwriting :(

Comment: I never said anything about PGP/GPG. Where did that come from? The link I sent you to mentions PGP/GPG as **not** a solution to the problem they are trying to solve.

Comment: How about [this one](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~sc609/talks/ed12stego.pdf). Try "Linguistic Steganography" in google scholar for more, that aren't too obvious.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's more like it: `spammimic[dot]com` I'll search more about it Sorry I read about pgp/gpg and didn't actually understand what that website was

Answer (score 1):

I have a very simple code of doing steganography that neither modifies any word of your original text nor poses any constraints on the words you employ in the text; it simply changes a little bit of where the individual lines end and should be barely detectable by the warden. However, it is fairly inefficient, capable of transmitting only 1 stego bit per line. (This is unfortunately owing to the Principle of No Free Lunch.) The code is availble at s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/6939954/1/

[Addendum] For obtaning better efficiency one can employ a recent linguistic steganographical scheme of mine: s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/9024439/1/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can embed message $A$ into message $B$ with simple $LSB$, but you will have message $B'$ and maybe  alter the meaning. If you want the message $B'$ to retain the original meaning, you should design $B$ to do that.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you mean Least Significant Bit by LSB? Also, it seems the last $B$ is supposed to be $B'$

Comment: Yes, I means least significant bit by LSB